# Angular JSPDF html2canvas image not displayed - has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to use jsdf to export a page to pdf. It works very well, the whole page is exported except for an image retrieved from an API (server I don't own). The image is displayed well on the web page but not on the pdf.

The images not coming from the API work well.

The code is as follows:

```
downloadPDF() {
    html2canvas(this.el.nativeElement).then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
        const doc = new jsPDF();

        const height = canvas.height * 208 / canvas.width;

        doc.addImage(imgData, 0, 0, 208, height);
        doc.save('image.pdf');
    });
}
```

No error is generated by this code but the image is not exported.

By adding the option `{useCORS: true}` as second parameter of html2canvas I got this error :

> Access to image at '[LINK API IMAGE]' from origin
> 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I don't understand why the policy cores are blocking for the export in pdf while the display on the web page is working fine, can you help me to understand and tell me how I can successfully export this image with jspdf?

thank you in advance

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No unfortunaly, i had to download my images and local to display them